# A simple 301 redirect creates an infinite loop in my htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I had this url on my website `example.com/foo.php` and I changed it to `example.com/foo` by doing this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ foo.php [NC,L]
```

And it works fine. However I'd like to do a 301 redirect from the old url to the new url. So I added this line in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^foo.php$ http://example.com/foo [L,NC,R=301]
```

And I get an infinite loop of redirects... How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  avoid the loop error using THE_REQUEST variable :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /foo\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo\.php$ http://example.com/foo [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^foo$ foo.php [NC,L]
```

Or if you are on apache 2.4, you can use the END flag

```
RewriteRule ^foo\.php$ http://example.com/foo [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^foo$ foo.php [NC,END]
```

Comment: The END tag solved my problem, thanks! Care to explain what it does?

Comment: END flag ends the rewrting process immideatly. otherwise without the END the target path foo.php matchs  pattern of the first rule again and creates an infinite internal redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the order it shouldn't loop work. Try the bellow works fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo.php$ http://example.com/foo [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^foo$ foo.php [NC,L]
```